# How to add a view as ListView header

Tags: android, listview, header, android-mapview

I have a View extending google MapView. And a ListView with items. What I need is to put MyMapView as a header to the list view. Help please what to do

Update: When I try to do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
View m = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, list, false);
list.addHeaderView(m);
```

I got an error:

> MapViews can only be created inside an instances of MapActivity

I think it's because I have removed my xml layout for map into different.xml from my activity

Answer (score 3):

Try this

*Create your ListViewHeader.xml first*

and do this

```
ListView lv = getListView(); // Your listView
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourHeader, lv, false);
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

take a look on [Android: Adding static header to the top of a ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620177/android-adding-static-header-to-the-top-of-a-listactivity)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
ListView.addHeaderView (View v)
```

before you set adapter to this ListView

Comment: @user1531195 this method must called before calling setAdapter
if it didn't help, you can try HeaderViewListAdapter

Comment: @user1531195 how exactly do you want it to look? Do you want the view to remain at the top of the screen when you scroll or do you want it to scroll together with the list elements?

Comment: Vikki, I want it to scroll together with the list elements, yep.

Comment: @user1531195 then this answer should work, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Read my initial post. I added info there

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a custom adapter, in getView() method provide different view at position 0.

```
if(position==0)
{
//Provide header view
}
else  
{
//provide normal row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to add a view as ListView header in android.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourLayoutFile,list, false);

list.addHeaderView(viewGroup, null, false);
```