# Making ListView scrolled with other items

Tags: android, listview

http://realdevs.tistory.com/entry/asdf

↑ Picture.

I have a problem when I use `ListView`.

As the screen is full of `widgets`, I would like the `ListView`'s items to be scrolled with other items in the `layout`.

On the picture, the blue one is a widget on the layout, and the red ones are the items of `ListView`.

When I scroll up the items, they move, but the blue one doesn't.

How can I make it to move together with `ListView` as it is an item in ListView?

Comment: Consider posting your layout file. It would be helpful as I am unable to open the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you an add your `blue layout` as your `listView` header.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620252/1436931) will help you in adding a layout as header.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add that blue part in scrollview

```
 <ScrollView
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  
           >

your layout
........


 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: it is not a good practice to include listview under scrollview.it wont work efficiently.

Comment: Don't put a ListView inside an ScrollView (with `android:orientation="vertical"`). It destroy the whole purpose of using the ListView. Not a good practice.

Comment: he does not mention that blue area is inside listview thats why i suggest him to add that blue area inside scroll view and you can give weight.

Answer (score 0):

From your pic in http://realdevs.tistory.com/entry/asdf

I'm implement in coding xml this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- this layout add your other items. I'm exam add Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butonTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Top Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- ListView in bottom screen and can auto scroll.  --> 
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dataListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>
```

`</LinearLayout>`