# Android: Attach ViewGroup as header of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, header, viewgroup

I have an activity in which I inflate an xml layout `(R.layout.listView)` that contains a listview (`@+id/listview`)
I want to give a header to that listView, but the header is a complex view from another xml (`R.layout.complexView`). It has a `LinearLayout` that groups a ton of `TextView`, `ImageView`, etc.
Its seems I can't find a way to inflate them both and then run the code

```
listview.addHeaderView(View view).
```

What code should I use in my Activity to achieve the desired effect?
The goal here is to make my whole view scrollable with my listView (same effect as the Google Maps restaurant details View)

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620177/android-adding-static-header-to-the-top-of-a-listactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.complexView, null, false);
listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

you have to set header view before setting the adapter